# Jackson Array to Pojo Not Working Only on Android

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I want to convert json array to POJO, it is working when running on JVM but failed on Android

This is my pojo:

```java
package com.binance.api.client.domain.market;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder()
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class Lilin {
    public Long openTime;

    public String open;

    public String high;

    public String low;

    public String close;

    public String volume;

    public Long closeTime;

    public String quoteAssetVolume;

    public Long numberOfTrades;

    public String takerBuyBaseAssetVolume;

    public String takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume;
}
```

And then test it manually:

```java
public void testCandlestickDeserializer() {
        final String candlestickJson = "[\n" +
                "    1499040000000,\n" +
                "        \"0.01634790\",\n" +
                "        \"0.80000000\",\n" +
                "        \"0.01575800\",\n" +
                "        \"0.01577100\",\n" +
                "        \"148976.11427815\",\n" +
                "        1499644799999,\n" +
                "        \"2434.19055334\",\n" +
                "        308,\n" +
                "        \"1756.87402397\",\n" +
                "        \"28.46694368\",\n" +
                "        \"17928899.62484339\"\n" +
                "        ]";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Lilin candlestick = mapper.readValue(candlestickJson, Lilin.class);
            System.out.println(candlestick);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

There is no error when try it on JVM but raises this error when run it on Android:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from String "0.01634790": not a valid Long value
```

it seems the `@JsonPropertyOrder()` annotation is not working properly on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you might have missed to define the property ordering, e.g from the docs:

Examples:

```
// ensure that "id" and "name" are output before other properties
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name" })
// order any properties that don't have explicit setting using alphabetic order

@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic=true)
//This annotation may or may not have effect on deserialization: for basic JSON handling there is no effect, but for other supported data types (or structural conventions) there may be.
```

Source: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html

Comment: Thank you, adding `@JsonPropertyOrder({"openTime", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume","closeTime","quoteAssetVolume","numberOfTrades","takerBuyBaseAssetVolume","takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume"})` works now